# Spark : How to design streaming with spark?

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark, bigdata, distributed-computing

**Current architecture**

MySQL database with a REST API abstraction.

**The problem**

MySQL not scaling for various reasons that including data model design which is hard to fix.

**Proposed architecture**

Using Cassandra as the NoSQL backend and using Spark as the in memory computation engine along with Spark streaming.

**Questions**

- How good is cassandra's consistency ? The decision is to directly use kafka streams that carries real time information into Cassandra and then use Spark SQL to query that data.
- If the consistency above is good, then how are RDD's designed around this since they are immutable.Do they create new RDD's ?
- An alternative design is to migrate all the data from MySQL to Cassandra and then use kafka to directly send the messages to spark which handles it in real time and use downstream systems to finally hand over the data to Cassandra over time.

In points 1&2 the consistency is dependant upon Cassandra and in point 3 it is tied with Spark.

Which design is better ? Can someone throw some light on this.

Comment: What kind of load do you have? Do you have many writes Are the only reads you do the ones from Spark? How many nodes are you planning to use? What is your data model, do you have a lot of inter table references (foreign keys) and would need a lot of joins? Also not sure why would you want to get the data from cassandra to kafka and then to spark, why not just poke cassandra directly?

Comment: Load is around 200 requests/sec, but mostly they are iterative i.e for reporting, so once the data is in memory it would not matter.Reads are more when compared with writes.There are around maximum of 4/5 joins with 2/3 tables at the max.I think you misunderstood the last point.Kafka is only for getting the data into spark/cassandra, I'll use direct connection with cassandra from spark.My question was whether to put that data into spark directly or to cassandra and then consume it in spark.

Comment: `migrate all the data from MySQL to Cassandra and then use kafka to directly send the messages to spark` this sounded like you'd do mysql -> cassandra -> kafka. Anyway haven't done any benchmarking recently but Cassandra wasn't the fastest when it came to reads, check if it changed. Any kinds of join in Cassandra (and most NoSQL) is a major pain in the butt so be careful. I also don't fully understand the "how are RDD's designed around this"? What do you mean by "do they create new RDD's"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.My understanding is RDD's are immutable, but spark streaming is where continuous flow of data is coming in, so when RDDs are immutable, how does it handle this continuous change in data ? And when I mean change in data, the new data must be combined with the old data for querying.

Comment: actually spark streaming is a micro batching technology, when getting data from it you don't get one `RDD` but instead a `DStream` which, internally, is a series of small `RDD`s so yes when data comes in Spark Streaming batches them (by time window) into new (immutable) `RDD`s.

Comment: Thanks for that information.I'll probably do some benchmarks and see what comes up.